# Where is the AMOC located in this Fig?

Tags: ocean-currents, atlantic, amoc

I am currently looking for a good illustration of the currents in the N atlantic. They should not be extremely complex, but they should be realistic. I have now found a figure that I am very happy with, but I am wondering where the AMOC is located in the figure, because the AMOC is NOT the Gulf Stream. Do you have better illustrations or do you know where the AMOC is located or why it is not specifically shown?

[image]

[Source](https://courses.seas.harvard.edu/climate/eli/Courses/misc/201209-Mallorca/Sources/2-THC/from-EPS131/2-RAPID/gulf_stream.php.html)

Comment: The AMOC is not a current

Comment: Hi, thanks i know it is a circulation, but i do Not know the differnce:(

Comment: The AMOC is a system of multiple surface currents and deep-water currents in the Atlantic Ocean. You need a full 3d plot for it

Comment: One good source is from the Woods Hole Oceanographic Institution: https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/whats-happening-with-the-amoc/

Comment: Ahhh perfect do you know a paper which summerises the currents which are countet to the amoc

Comment: Perfect thank you soo much :)

Comment: Also: https://www.whoi.edu/know-your-ocean/ocean-topics/how-the-ocean-works/ocean-circulation/the-ocean-conveyor/

Comment: Can you write an answer so i can give U Credits for this

Comment: I don't have time right now to craft a good answer, but if you get info from the sites and put it as an answer, I will be happy to help edit and upvote it