# Which currents are counted as AMOC in the North Atlantic and which are not?

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents, ocean-models, amoc, northatlantic

This question is related to this [question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25958/where-is-the-amoc-located-in-this-fig). I am currently trying to understand which currents in the North Atlantic are counted as part of the AMOC:

I am sure about the currents:

1. N. Atlantic current
2. Norwegian Current
3. Gulf Stream

For the currents:

1. Norwegan Current
2. Baffin Bay
3. Canarias current
4. North Atlantic Deep Water Current
5. Irminger Current
6. West Greenland Current
7. E Greenland Current
8. Irminger Current
9. North Iceland Irminger Current

I´m not so sure. I find some contradictory [literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_Current) (I do know Wiki isn´t the best source but nice to get an overview) on these currents. Whilst some mention these currents, they are hardly mentioned in other [literature](https://www.whoi.edu/know-your-ocean/ocean-topics/how-the-ocean-works/ocean-circulation/the-ocean-conveyor/).

Even this figure didn´t make it clear which currents are related towards the AMOC

[image]

Do you have a good list of which currents are included?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert but you might be wrong with the gulf stream. As far as I know the AMOC is driven by thermohaline effects. The gulf stream, in contrast, is largely wind driven.

Comment: Hi thanks :) but When I google I found this: The best known segment of this circulation (AMOC) is the Gulf Stream, a wind-driven gyre, which transports warm water from the Caribbean northwards.  (Its from Wiki so this have to been taken with a grain of salt :))

Comment: I guess it boils down to definitions. To me saying that the AMOC is a thermohaline circulation, which wikipedia does, and then giving a wind driven circulation as an example makes no sense.